# Output joining two tables in a certain format

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

The question is to write a SQL Query joining these two tables:

T1

Column X

- A
- A
- A
- B
- B

T2

Column Y

- A
- A
- B

Join these two tables to get the result in this format:

Column 1 Column 2

- A      A
- A      A
- A      NULL
- B      B
- B      NULL

If I do a left join, I will get extra rows, if I do distinct then I will get fewer rows since it will eliminate the duplicates.

Please guide me on how to approach this.

Comment: Are there any columns (other  than X/Y) in T1 & T2?

Comment: "Please guide me" is not a valid SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to rank records in both tables with `row_number()`, then use that information to join the tables:

```
select t1.x, t2.y
from (select x, row_number() over(partition by x order by x) rn from t1) t1
left join (select y, row_number() over(partition by y order by y) rn from t2) t2 
    on t2.y = t1.x and t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Note: window function `row_number()` is available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: This looks good. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RJ07 Note, the results for this query are not guaranteed to be consistent. If there are other columns you want to show, or it matters which A or B records you show alongside each other, this can play tricks on you. It's still the best way to do it... you just want to be more specific in the `order by` if you can.